# Associated records count is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

In console I do:

```
board = FactoryGirl.build(:board_with_source)

board.sources
=> [#<Board id: 6, name: "Free Ruby Books", description: "Ruby Books - Free and Paid ones", created_at: "2013-06-21 12:21:34", updated_at: "2013-06-21 12:21:34", user_id: nil>]

board.sources.count
=> 0
```

Why it shows 0 ?

FactoryGirl setup:

```
# Read about factories at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :board do
    name "Ruby Books"
    description "Ruby Books - Free and Paid ones"
  end

  factory :board_with_source, parent: :board do
    after :build do |board|
      board.sources << FactoryGirl.create(:board, name: "Free Ruby Books")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you used `build`, which only build an object in memory but not persist in db.

The `count` method will query db as "SELECT COUNT(*)....". So your count is zero.

*Add*

To show the counts in console, you can use `size` method

```
s1 = @board.sources.new(attr)
s1.save!
@board.sources.count
# => 1
@board.sources.size
# => 1

s2 = @board.sources.new(attr)
@board.sources.count
# => 1
@board.sources.size
# => 2
```